# Remove the second instance of a character from a string

Tags: bash, git

I am working on making a git command I use more useful. A common task I do is to `grep` my `git rev-list --all`. I wrote (aka cut and pasted another StackExchange answer) git command to do this for me.

`~/bin/git-search`:

```
!/bin/bash
function _search() {
    git rev-list --all | (
        while read revision; do
            git grep -F $1 $revision
        done
    )
}
_search $1
```

The output from this looks like:

`f26ce56cf6b17401292c494f906b2b6a9071ca75:filename.py:grepped string`

I usually take these results and run `git show` along with the commit and file path to see that particular version of the file. `git show` takes the input of `{COMMIT HASH}:path/to/file`.

What I'd ideally like is to have my git function stick a whitespace where the second `:` is, which would allow me more easily copy and paste the output of `git-search` into `git show`, ie:

`f26ce56cf6b17401292c494f906b2b6a9071ca75:filename.py grepped string`

I'd like to use BASH for this as I am already using BASH. My initial solution was to use Python but that seems needless to me. I just am not sure how best to achieve this in BASH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/:/ /2'
```

This would change the second `:` character to a space.

You could stick that in as an extra stage of your function's pipeline:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

git rev-list --all |
while read revision; do
    git grep -F "$1" "$revision"
done |
sed 's/:/ /2'
```

(I actually deleted the function as it didn't seem to be needed; note also the quoting of the variable expansions; oh, and it's a `/bin/sh` script since it's not using any `bash`-specific features (neither did yours, except for the unneeded `function` keyword))

Comment: That's perfect! And thanks for the other improvements as well.
I wasn't aware `sed` could do this. Does that mean I can swap out the `2` for a `3` to remove the third instance? I only knew about `d`, `e`, and `g`. Guess I have a lot of `sed` to learn still.

Comment: @IanPringle Yes, you can swap out the `2` for `3` or any other positive integer. There is no `d` flag to the `s` command in `sed` (not even in GNU `sed`). I assume that you're thinking about the `d` _commad_ in `sed`.

Comment: @kusalanada That's great! Yes, I guess that's true the `d` replaces the `s`. Thanks again!